# table:tr and gradient not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, gradient

I want to fill the table row background to x percent.

My problem is that when table cell's width is not 100%, the background color does not appear correctly.

Html :

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS :

```
table {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
border-spacing: 0;
}
#tr1 {
background: #7CB663; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 50%, #ffffff 50%); /*      FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,
color-stop(50%,#7CB663), color-stop(50%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 50%,#ffffff 50%); /*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 50%,#ffffff 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 50%,#ffffff 50%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,#7CB663 50%,#ffffff 50%); /* W3C */
background-attachment: fixed;
}
#tr2 {
background: #7CB663; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 40%, #ffffff 40%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(40%,#7CB663),
color-stop(40%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 40%,#ffffff 40%); /*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 40%,#ffffff 40%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 40%,#ffffff 40%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,#7CB663 40%,#ffffff 40%); /* W3C */
background-attachment: fixed;
}
#tr3 {
background: #7CB663; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 20%, #ffffff 20%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(20%,#7CB663),
color-stop(20%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 20%,#ffffff 20%); /*Chrome10+,Safari5.1+*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 20%,#ffffff 20%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,#7CB663 20%,#ffffff 20%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,#7CB663 20%,#ffffff 20%); /* W3C */
background-attachment: fixed;
}
td {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Output :

[image]

Has anyone a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your problem is that the gradient stops aren't relative to the table width, but to the width of `body`.

Looks like that's because you're setting `background-attachment: fixed`. Getting rid of that property did the trick for me.

[edited JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ndjp15nb/1/)

Comment: I use the "background-attachment: fixed" to fill the complete tr not only each td.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your background gradient has been stopped at 50%, if you need to display color in full tr width, use following css

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, #7cb663 50%, #ffffff 100%) repeat fixed 0 0;
```

this css will help you to repeat color in full width.

Comment: and is it possible to get a hard cut at x percent? Now i have the green over the full tr, but i want the green till x percent.

Comment: then you have to give light green color instead of heard white. It is because you green gradient is over at 50% width of tr.